# ZF2 Cookies for affiliates

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies

I am attempting to write a cookie class to store referral information and need a bit of guidance.

The [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.config.html) on this seems a little sparse.

As with any affiliate programme, the idea is to grab information from a link: http://example.com/referrer_id=123 and to store this on the users computer for later use.

So this is what I have thus far:

**Controller:**

```
    $cookieObject = new CookieService();

    $cookieObject->setCookie(
        [
            'value' => [
                'name' => 'test',
                'referring_site'=>'test site'
            ]
        ]
    );

    die(var_dump($cookieObject->getCookie()));
```

**CookieService class:**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Library\Session;

use Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie;
use Zend\Http\Cookies;
class CookieService extends SetCookie
{
    public function __construct() {

        $this->cookie = new SetCookie();
        $this->header = new Cookies();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new cookie
     * @param $params
     */
    public function setCookie($params)
    {
        $key = (isset($params['key'])) ? $params['key'] : 'referrer';
        $value = (isset($params['value'])) ? $params['value'] : [];
        $expires = (isset($params['time'])) ? time() + $params['time'] : time() +  365 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        /**
         * Test whether the cookie exists before updating
         */
        if (!$this->exists($key))
        {
            $this->cookie->setName($key);
            $this->cookie->setValue($value);
            $this->cookie->setExpires($expires);
            $this->header->addCookie($this->cookie);
        }


    }

    /**
     * Get a cookie based on a given key
     * @param string $key
     * @return null
     */
    public function getCookie($key = 'referrer')
    {
        $cookieArray = $this->header->getAllCookies();

        foreach ($cookieArray AS $cookie)
        {
            if ($cookie->name === $key)
            {
                return $cookie;
            }
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * Returns whether a cookie exists or not
     * @param $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public function exists($key)
    {
        return ( $this->getCookie($key) ) ? true : false;
    }

}
```

**I am struggling with the following:**

If I save a cookie then close the browser, the cookie is deleted. I can't seem to find any documentation that clearly covers this use.

Any advice, greatly appreciated.

**ND: The dump of the cookie object:**

```
object(Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie)[1085]   
    protected 'name' => string 'referrer' (length=8)   
    protected 'value' => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'test' (length=4)
      'referring_site' => string 'test site' (length=9)   
    protected 'version' => null   
    protected 'maxAge' => null   
    protected 'expires' => int 1475931242   
    protected 'domain' => null   
    protected 'path' => null   
    protected 'secure' => boolean false   
    protected 'quoteFieldValue' => boolean false   
    protected 'httponly' => boolean false   
    public 'type' => string 'Cookie' (length=6)
```

Comment: The set cookie stuff looks correct, but you should be adding that header to the existing HTTP Response. Don't touch `Zend\Http\Cookies` at all. The docs you linked to have nothing to do with setting cookies.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I ended up just writing a basic class using the $_COOKIE function. Will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so I have written my own class to deal with this. It is pretty simple:

```
 <?php
namespace Application\Library\Session;

/**
 * Use this service to set persistent cookies on a users machine
 * Class CookieService
 * @package Application\Library\Session
 */

class CookieService
{

    /**
     * Create a new cookie
     * @param $params
     */
    public function setCookie($params)
    {
        $name = (isset($params['name'])) ? $params['name'] : 'referrer';
        $value = (isset($params['value'])) ? $params['value'] : '';
        $expire = (isset($params['expire'])) ? time() + $params['expire'] : time() +  365 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        $path = (isset($params['path'])) ? $params['path'] : '';
        $domain = (isset($params['domain'])) ? $params['domain'] : '';
        $secure = (isset($params['secure'])) ? $params['secure'] : 0;
        $httponly = (isset($params['httponly'])) ? $params['httponly'] : 1;

        /**
         * Test whether the cookie exists before updating
         */
        if (!$this->exists($name))
        {
            setcookie(
                $name,
                $value,
                $expire ,
                $path ,
                $domain ,
                $secure ,
                $httponly
            );
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get a cookie based on a given key
     * @param string $name
     * @return null
     */
    public function getCookie($name = 'referrer')
    {
        return (isset($_COOKIE[$name])) ? $_COOKIE[$name] : null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether a cookie exists or not
     * @param $name
     * @return bool
     */
    public function exists($name)
    {
        return ( $this->getCookie($name) ) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a cookie
     * @param $name
     */
    function deleteCookie($name)
    {
        if ($this->exists($name))
        {
            setcookie($name, "", time()-(60*60*24) );
        }
    }

}
```